# How to call a model from with in a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model witch is holding different values in my website and i am currently trying to retrieve the value token.

I call my model in the following way:

```
HoldToken t = new HoldToken();
string token = t.Token;
```

This is how the model looks

```
namespace MvcResComm.Models
{

    public class HoldToken
    {
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am always receiving null as my returned token. I think this is because i am using the `new` keyword.

How can i instantiate the model `HoldToken` with out newing it?

Comment: :S How are we supposed to know why it is null, from 2 lines of code?

Comment: Your question is to vague, who knows about HoldToken? Try to clarify the question, add more code, describe better your situation, your app and ask a real question.

Comment: Did you ever set Token to a valid string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you're using a constructor-less class and an automatic property.

I'd guess that you're not setting the HoldToken automatic property, which is why you're getting the null.

Add a new parameterless constructor and make sure the Token member is initialised in some way.

```
public HoldToken() 
{
   // Set value of token here
   // Guessing at how you'd instantiate it.
   Token = new Token();
}
```